# MS build of solution which references dll from other class library project.

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, msbuild

I am using Jenkins for CI.

My application- ( solution name HP_app) is a vb.net windows forms ( repository https://XXXXXX.org/scm/HP/HP_app.git)

Windows forms References .dll from  class library (solution name HP_app_lib)(repository https://XXXXXX.org/scm/HP/HP_app_lib.git)

I have set up  two separate Jenkins job for each solution.Class library solution builds perfectly.Now windows forms solution is dependent on HP_app_lib.dll.

```
<SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\HP_app_lib\bin\Debug\HP_app_lib.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

How can I build windows forms using msbuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
As windows forms solution is  Referencing class
 library-Which alone stand alone VS solution  also going continuous changes.

```
Below project reference in MSBuild file is changed from 
     <HintPath>..\HP_app_lib\bin\Debug\HP_app_lib.dll</HintPath>

To file path in Jenkins server <HintPath>C:\jenkins\workspace\CI_FASET_LIB\bin\Debug\FASETLib.dll</HintPath>
```

Few more tips.
Normally Build servers will not come with Visual Studio installed.Jenkins MS build is searching for Microsoft.office.Interop.word.dll and ADODB.dll in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5`.

So I have moved these dll's from dev machine to Build server .net framework path.

Dev machine as we got VS,these are located in.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14
```

Comment: could you elaborate where i have to modify in jenkins

Answer (score 0):

@user2211290 The windows form project and that assembly files structure should be like this:
HP_app_lib

--bin

```
--Debug

    --\HP_app_lib.dll
```

[windows form project folder (e.g. HP_app)]

--[windows form project name].vbproj

After that build windows form project directly through msbuild, for example: MSBuild [windows form project name].vbproj.